# A Deadly Person

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is filthy.
>
> My infix is the prefix.
>
> My suffix is a preposition.
>
> Together, I am to kill someone.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be

> Assassin

My prefix is filthy.

> Ass = a person's buttocks.

My infix is the prefix.

> Ass, again (same as prefix)

My suffix is a preposition.

> In

Together, I am to kill someone.

> Assassin = one who murders an important person.